# Can I disable the Add File dropdown on a personal GitHub repository?

Tags: github

GitHub projects support adding files via the web interface, as documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/managing-files-on-github/adding-a-file-to-a-repository

I would like to completely disable this for one of my projects, but if there's a setting to do this I don't know where it is.  Is it possible to disable the "Add file" dropdown?

Comment: Why? Typically you just make master a protected branch that can only be merged to via a PR which requires approval.

Comment: The answer to "Why" is that I want people to have a local copy of the repo they're working with, rather than using the Add File dropdown.  This is irrespective of whether master is protected.

EDIT: Separately, I don't want to protect master, because except for this _one button_ it doesn't fit my use case -- I'm running a project where I don't expect people to make branches for their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem configurable.

Similarly, [disabling commits through web interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64127057/6309) (which would have met your requirement) is also not configurable.
This could be a feature request to make to GitHub support.